# MongoDB service on custom port not running

Tags: linux, mongodb, service

I created another mongo host besides the default one (:27017) on port :37017.

But I cannot seem to start the service on that port.

When I checked with `netstat -lnp | grep mongod` the results are :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28017               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21533/mongod        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21533/mongod
```

Here's my config for the other host :

```
dbpath = /usr/local/mongodb/mysite/data/
logpath = /usr/local/mongodb/mysite/log/mongodb.log
pidfilepath = /usr/local/mongodb/mysite/log/mongod.pid
logappend = true
port = 37017
fork = true
smallfiles = true
```

Tried using mongod `--port 37017` with no luck, and no googling seems to bear any result.

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by specifying different port numbers and data directories for the other instances of mongod, and then specifying the new port number in the client.

For example:

./mongod --dbpath /foo/bar/otherpath --port some_other_port

https://serverfault.com/questions/296246/multiple-mongos-on-one-server

This link would be more helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok